# Stripe integration in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stripe-payments

I am using Unity 2017.2.1f1 running Experimental .NET 4.6 equivalent scripting runtime version with .NET 4.6 compatibility level.

However when i install te latest version of [Stripe.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/) (which requires .NET 4.0) using nuget packet manager i get the error `Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Stripe' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` when trying to use the stripe namespace.

I am fairly sure this is being caused by Monodevelop somehow interfering as i am able to use the `Stripe` namespace when I create a clean .net project and get the very same package with nuget.

Is there a different way to install the Stripe.net library that would allow me to use the namespace?

```
using Stripe; // not found (in a Unity project)
public class StripeAuthenticate 
{
   void InitStripe()
   {
       StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("stripe_key");
   }
}
```

I tried removing the Monobehaviour inheritence but that did not do anything either.

I have tried following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489143/namespace-not-found-for-stripe-net) but since i was already using nuget from the start that didn't do anything for me.

edit: I am aware of [UniStripe](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/billing/unistripe-40081) but this hasn't been updated in years, coupled with the negative reviews I do not feel comfortable using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly the issue lies with Nuget rather than with Monobehaviour.

As Unity pulls all its resources starting from the /Assets/ folder it does not find any libraries installed through the nuget package manager which defaults its download location to what seems to be `$(Solutiondir)/packages/<packageName>` which is above unity's asset folder.

I got around this issue using the following steps:

- Install Stripe using nuget
- Navigate to SolutionDir/packages
- *Copy* Stripe and newtonsoft /lib/ folder to a temporary location
- *Uninstal* the packages using nuget
- Move the /lib/ folder into a directory inside /assets/

without uninstalling the packages using nuget first i was getting a ton of error messages saying stripe was already defined.

Comment: In my case this doesn't work, if I do that, the follow message appears: PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name Stripe.net.dll included or the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform.

Comment: @Lotan Somewhere in your project is another dll that shares the same name, make sure you delete the other version from your project before importing a new version

Comment: I did that, the only way was to remove all Stripe and Newtonsoft dll's except net45 directory :(